# Inserting results from one table to another with consecutive dates for each inserted row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my asp.net App I have SqlDataSource with following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Invitations (PatientId, PlanId)
SELECT TOP 10 Patients.Id, @PlanId
FROM Patients
```

So basically it gets 10 rows from `Patients` table and inserts them (certain values) to `Invitations` table. `@PlanId` is additional parameter passed to SqlDataSource.

What I need is to insert value into third column called `Time` which is of type `time(0), not null`. But I would like this value to be generated somehow like this:

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i) Time = @InitialTime + i * Interval

So for example:

```
row 1: PatientId = 0; PlanId = 555; Time = 12:00
row 2: PatientId = 1; PlanId = 555; Time = 12:05
row 3: PatientId = 2; PlanId = 555; Time = 12:10
```

So I pass `@InitialTime` param and Time field is generated based on it with some interval...

Is it possible in MSSQL?

Comment: You mean something like `DateAdd( minute, PatientId * @Interval, @InitialTime )`? Or don't you expect `PatientId` to be a sequential zero-based value coming from a `select top` query without an `order by` clause?

Comment: Why would you want to calculate the time in this way? It won't map to the time that the entry was made. Are you asking how to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
INSERT INTO Invitations (PatientId, PlanId, [Time])
SELECT TOP 10 
  Patients.Id, 
  @PlanId, 
  DATEADD(MINUTE,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Patients.Id) -1) * 5 ,@InitialTime ) AS [Time]
FROM Patients
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not MS-SQL user at all,

This pseudo code may help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertFromOtherTable
AS

DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 10 Patients.Id, @PlanId FROM Patients

DECLARE @startTime DATETIME, @interval INT

OPEN my_cur

while (read_one_row_from_cursor)
loop 
   -- insert the data into other table
   -- increment the timer
   -- continue loop to next row
end loop;

CLOSE my_cur
```